# How to check if a pattern is contained in a register's content?

Tags: search, regular-expression, register, find

I'm writing a new plugin and as part of a function, I need to check that a register contains a particular **pattern**.

I checked the official documentation but couldn't manage to use any of the `search()` or `substitute()` functions for this purpose.

Any idea how this could be done?

(Suppose the register is `"o` and the pattern is *Image*).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the content of the register `"o` you can use:

```
getreg('o')
```

This will return the content of the register as a string.

To match a string you can use `match()`:

```
echo match(getreg('o'), 'image')
```

You'll get `-1` if the register doesn't contain `image` and a positive interger otherwise.

See

- [`:h getreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getreg%28%29)
- [`:h match()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#match%28%29)